# Declaring multiple instances of a TFT screen class?

Tags: c++, arduino

Undoubtedly due to my lack of encyclopedic knowledge of C/C++, I have found myself in a quagmire while trying to initialize multiple instances of a TFT screen class.  The TFT screen is the Adafruit_SSD1331, and I would like to have one small sketch control more than one of these with identical code.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
slapbmp.ino:61:5: error: 'tft' in 'class Adafruit_SSD1331' does not name a type
slapbmp.ino:62:5: error: 'tft' in 'class Adafruit_SSD1331' does not name a type
slapbmp.ino:63:3: error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration
```

...when I try to to compile this code:

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1331.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>


// If we are using the hardware SPI interface, these are the pins (for future ref)
#define sclk 13
#define mosi 11
#define rst  9

#define cs   10
#define dc   8

#define cs2  5
#define dc2  4


// Color definitions
#define BLACK           0x0000
#define BLUE            0x001F
#define RED             0xF800
#define GREEN           0x07E0
#define CYAN            0x07FF
#define MAGENTA         0xF81F
#define YELLOW          0xFFE0  
#define WHITE           0xFFFF

// to draw images from the SD card, we will share the hardware SPI interface

namespace STD {
  typedef struct Adafruit_SSD1331
  {
  } tft;
}  

namespace initScreens {
  typedef struct {
    Adafruit_SSD1331::tft scr1 = Adafruit_SSD1331(cs, dc, rst);
    Adafruit_SSD1331::tft scr2 = Adafruit_SSD1331(cs2, dc2, rst);
  };
};

// For Arduino Uno/Duemilanove, etc
//  connect the SD card with MOSI going to pin 11, MISO going to pin 12 and SCK going to pin 13 (standard)
//  Then pin 4 goes to CS (or whatever you have set up)
#define SD_CS 3    // Set the chip select line to whatever you use (4 doesnt conflict with the library)
#define SD_CS2 2

// the file itself
File bmpFile;

// information we extract about the bitmap file
int bmpWidth, bmpHeight;
uint8_t bmpDepth, bmpImageoffset;

void setup(void) {  //...
```

Just as a note, I'm trying to use the struct in a way that allows me to not have to modify any*.h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with namespacing.
The compiler error tells you that the compiler wasn't able to find the name, the reason it couldn't was because the name `tft` is within the `STD` namespace here. You need to fix that or change how the code is designed.

Given that this is C++ I would change things a few things to make use of C++ language features:

```
//get rid of some of the #defines
const int cs = 10;
const int dc = 8;

//Make a struct to contain info about the screens 
struct Screens {
    Adafruit_SSD1331 scr1;
    Adafruit_SSD1331 scr2;

    Screens():
       scr1(cs, dc, rst),
       scr2(cs2, dc2, rst)
    { }
};
```

Then you can just instantiate this class once in `setup` if this is using the Arduino convention. (Or place somewhere appropriate before you enter your main loop)

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't that simple, although I will admit there are likely multiple errors int his code.  `slapbmp.ino:61:5: error: 'tft' in 'struct STD::Adafruit_SSD1331' does not name a type
slapbmp.ino:62:5: error: 'tft' in 'struct STD::Adafruit_SSD1331' does not name a type
slapbmp.ino:63:3: error: missing type-name in typedef-declaration`

Comment: @gustable, ah I see the mistake I made. Honestly I'd just change the code here as suggested in my edit. There's quite a few things about this code that could be imrpoved, might make a good post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ once you get it working.

Comment: I just looked at the header file over on github and I'd certainly try to encapsulate this behaviour, I think that discussion goes outside the scope of an answer here but would be more appropriate over on codereview, ping me if you end up posting over there.